# bash assign default value

Tags: bash

> ${parameter:=word}
>                 Assign Default Values.  If parameter is unset or null, the
>   expansion of word is assigned to
>   parameter.  The value of parameter is
>   then  substituted.   Positional 
>   parameters  and  special
>                 parameters may not be assigned to in this way.

I thought I could use this feature to write `${LONG_VARIABLE_NAME:=hello}` instead of the longer `LONG_VARIABLE_NAME=${LONG_VARIABLE_NAME:-hello}`, but now bash also tries to execute 'hello' and that gives a command not found. Any way to avoid that? Or will I have to stick to the latter? Can someone give an example where the assign default is actually useful?

Comment: When quoting text it's helpful to include a link to the source.

Answer (score 281, accepted):

Use a colon:

```
: ${A:=hello}
```

The colon is a null command that does nothing and ignores its arguments. It is built into bash so a new process is not created.

Comment: I can't help but observe that `: ${A:=hello}` is exactly as long as `A=${A:-hello}`. It also seems that the latter is a little less esoteric and its intent is more clear. Using `:`, which is basically a no-op, seems kludgy by comparison to the way the OP was doing it before.

Comment: @DanMoulding: I don't think either solution is satisfactory. I do not like the stuttering of the second form, so I slightly prefer a run of `:` lines at the start of a script to set defaults. (also, they are only the same length for single character variable names).

Comment: @camh: Agreed. I can see where, if you had a lot of variables to initialize to defaults and they have long names, the `:` approach would be prefereable, both for typing and for reading. Yes, this seems like an area where Bash could use a little improvement.

Comment: @DanMoulding: what about `: ${VERY_LONG_VARIABLE_NAME:=hello}` vs. : `VERY_LONG_VARIABLE_NAME=${VERY_LONG_VARIABLE_NAME:-hello}`. I hope you use descriptive variable names in your code :)

Comment: Not just shorter, but less error-prone: `VERY_LONG_VARIABLE_NAME=${VERY_LOGN_VARIABLE_NAME:-hello}`. Oops.

Comment: Only this format can be used with positional parameters: `${1:-2}`.

Comment: An advantage of the `A=$A:-hello` approach is that its self-documenting when run with `set -x`.  That is, the assignment will print as `A=hello` whereas the null command would only print the value (`hello`).

Comment: Not working in bash, answer from Jonathan L works like a charm

Comment: @develCuy I think you're wrong. This most definitely does work in bash; I've used it plenty. Have you got more to add than "not working"? Jonathan L's answer has this answer within it too, so perhaps you just mistyped?

Answer (score 238):

Please look at http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/parameter-substitution.html for examples

```
${parameter-default}, ${parameter:-default}
```

If parameter not set, use default. After the call, parameter is still not set.
Both forms are almost equivalent. The extra `:` makes a difference only when parameter has been declared, but is null.

```
unset EGGS
echo 1 ${EGGS-spam}   # 1 spam
echo 2 ${EGGS:-spam}  # 2 spam

EGGS=
echo 3 ${EGGS-spam}   # 3
echo 4 ${EGGS:-spam}  # 4 spam

EGGS=cheese
echo 5 ${EGGS-spam}   # 5 cheese
echo 6 ${EGGS:-spam}  # 6 cheese
```

---

```
${parameter=default}, ${parameter:=default}
```

If parameter not set, set parameter value to default.
Both forms nearly equivalent. The : makes a difference only when parameter has been declared and is null

```
# sets variable without needing to reassign
# colons suppress attempting to run the string
unset EGGS
: ${EGGS=spam}
echo 1 $EGGS     # 1 spam
unset EGGS
: ${EGGS:=spam}
echo 2 $EGGS     # 2 spam

EGGS=
: ${EGGS=spam}
echo 3 $EGGS     # 3        (set, but blank -> leaves alone)
EGGS=
: ${EGGS:=spam}
echo 4 $EGGS     # 4 spam

EGGS=cheese
: ${EGGS:=spam}
echo 5 $EGGS     # 5 cheese
EGGS=cheese
: ${EGGS=spam}
echo 6 $EGGS     # 6 cheese
```

---

```
${parameter+alt_value}, ${parameter:+alt_value}
```

If parameter set, use alt_value, else use null string. After the call, parameter value not changed.
Both forms nearly equivalent. The : makes a difference only when parameter has been declared and is null

```
unset EGGS
echo 1 ${EGGS+spam}  # 1
echo 2 ${EGGS:+spam} # 2

EGGS=
echo 3 ${EGGS+spam}  # 3 spam
echo 4 ${EGGS:+spam} # 4

EGGS=cheese
echo 5 ${EGGS+spam}  # 5 spam
echo 6 ${EGGS:+spam} # 6 spam
```

Answer (score 27):

The default value parameter expansion is often useful in build scripts like the example one below.  If the user just calls the script as-is, perl will not be built in. The user has to explicitly set `WITH_PERL` to a value other than "no" to have it built in.

```
$ cat defvar.sh
#!/bin/bash

WITH_PERL=${WITH_PERL:-no}

if [[ "$WITH_PERL" != no ]]; then
    echo "building with perl"
    # ./configure --enable=perl
else
    echo "not building with perl"
    # ./configure
fi
```

Build *without* Perl

```
$ ./defvar.sh
not building with perl
```

Build *with* Perl

```
$ WITH_PERL=yes ./defvar.sh
building with perl
```

Comment: The question is about the "assign default value" syntax (`:=`), not the "use default value" syntax (`:-`).

Answer (score 4):

You can also use `:=` construct to assign and decide on action in one step. Consider following example:

```
# Example of setting default server and reporting it's status

server=$1
if [[ ${server:=localhost} =~ [a-z] ]]      # 'localhost' assigned here to $server
then    echo "server is localhost"          # echo is triggered since letters were found in $server
else
        echo "server was set" # numbers were passed
fi
```

If `$1` is not empty, `localhost` will be assigned to `server` in the `if` condition field, trigger match and report match result. In this way you can assign on the fly and trigger appropriate action.