# input data automatically into read variable on bash script

Tags: bash

How can i detect the servers domain name and automatically have it inputted so i can just press enter

```
    echo "
Please enter your domain name : "
read Domain
echo $Domain > /root/domain.info
Hostname=server.$Domain
```

Thanks,
Chris

Comment: assuming this is a linux server, and not Microsoft Windows, depending on your linux distribution see if you have the environment variable `$dnsdomainname` or `$domainname`.  If so problem solved.  Also look at http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/38209/how-to-get-the-hostname-along-with-the-domain-name

Comment: can also do a `if [ -z "$domainname" ]` for example to check if there is a domain name set, if not then prompt user to enter something.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11686208/check-if-environment-variable-is-already-set

Answer (score 1):

```
Hostname=$(uname -n) #or $(hostname -f)
Nameserver=$(cat /etc/resolv.conf)
```

To check if it is set:

```
if [ -z "$Hostname" ];then  
read -p "Give name " name
Hostname=$name
fi
```

Also notice that Linux / UNIX comes with the following utilities to display hostname / domain name:

a) hostname – show or set hostname
b) domainname – show or set NIS/YP domain name
c) dnsdomainname – show DNS domain name
d) nisdomainname – show or set NIS/YP domain name
e) ypdomainname – show or set NIS/YP domain name

Comment: While this does indeed get your host name, very frequently that ISN"T the FQDN that "the world" uses to get to the box.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want to *prefill the edit buffer* when you use the `read` builtin.

Bash v4+ allows you to do that by combining the `-e` option (which activates `readline` library support) with `-i <editBufferDefault>`; e.g.:

```
editBufferDefault=$(domainname)  # get default value to offer to the user
read -e -p "Please enter your domain name: " -i "$editBufferDefault"
```